# Trying to set sortable element to be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using jQuery Sortable to order list items. However I have set certain li elements with a disable class name in order to disable the sorting of that specific item.
I have also added the class to the jquery code to disable however it still allows those items to be rearranged

I have looked at various sources  that have said simply use enable / disable on the selector however noneseem to work
I've searched SO and also looked here http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-option

```
 <script>
 $( function() {
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
 $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
 $(".notsortable").sortable("disable");
 } );
 </script>
 <ul id="sortable">
 <li class="ui-state-default notsortable">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #1</li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #2</li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #5</li>
   <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #7</li>
     </ul>
```

The list item shouldnt be allowed to be move however this is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
  })
});
```

```css
.ui-state-disabled {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><a href="https://www.google.com/">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #2
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #3
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #4
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #5
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #6
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Order #7
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick
Didnt think it would make the item itself unselectable though as I was planning on making the Order # a link to a panel which when clicked would show the order info

Comment: @ChrisYates updated code, you can make it clickable with 2 lines of CSS :-)

Comment: Out of curiousity, I've searched but cant find anything on this.. I dont suppose its possible to move certain items up only not down ?

Comment: @ChrisYates that's not possible unfortunately